# Adding java project to RCP project's build path

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp

In Eclipse I have created RCP Plugin project.
I also created simple java project.

I've added simple java project to build path of RCP project.

So I am able to import and compile code in RCP, but when I start the RCP application, upon reaching code that uses the added java project I get exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
```

How can I solve this (without creating a jar of java project and adding it as library to rcp project)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Everything** in an RCP must be included in one of the plugins.

You need to build a jar file from your simple Java project and put that jar in one of the plugins included in the RCP.